# Kafka topic is not created (ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException)

Tags: apache-kafka, timeoutexception

I unpack Kafka on my Linux stand, then I did:

start zookeeper:

```
./zookeeper-server-start.sh
```

output:

```
USAGE: ./zookeeper-server-start.sh [-daemon] zookeeper.properties
```

start kafka-server

```
./kafka-server-start.sh
```

output:

```
USAGE: ./kafka-server-start.sh [-daemon] server.properties [--override property=value]*
```

then i tried to create topic

```
./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic fss-fsstransdata
```

but got exception

```
Exception in thread "main" kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$$anonfun$kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected$1.apply$mcV$sp(ZooKeeperClient.scala:259)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$$anonfun$kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected$1.apply(ZooKeeperClient.scala:255)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$$anonfun$kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected$1.apply(ZooKeeperClient.scala:255)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:253)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:255)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:113)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1857)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$ZookeeperTopicService$.apply(TopicCommand.scala:321)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:54)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

Please, help to resolve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from your outputs:

```
USAGE: ./zookeeper-server-start.sh [-daemon] zookeeper.properties
USAGE: ./kafka-server-start.sh [-daemon] server.properties [--override property=value]*
```

You need to specify those `properties` file if you want to start the servers, those files are in `config` directory under kafka home.

So to start zookeeper:

```
./zookeeper-server-start.sh ../config/zookeeper.properties
```

then to start kafka-server

```
./kafka-server-start.sh ../config/server.properties
```

Then, try creating the topics

Comment: I thought it was reported which configs were applied. This is stupid. Thank u :)